# How to build redirect uri for Mobile App for SSO

Tags: openid-connect, mobile-application, redirect-uri

I am building the **OpenId-Connect (OIDC) Provider** to support SSO on **Web Application**, **iOS Application**, **Android application**.

After the **OIDC Provider** authenticated user, it will redirect user back to the Application (Web, iOS, android) with **authorization-code**. Client will use the **authorization-code** to obtain the **token**.

For the **Web Application**, I know the **redirect-uri** is the Web Application URL, eg: https://client-web-application-url/oauth-callback. The **OIDC Provider** will redirect user back to this URL including the **authorization-code** on the query string.

However, for the **iOS** and **android** application, I don't know what its redirect-uri to redirect to. I only know the **iOS Bundle Id** and the **android Package Name**.

How can I build the **redirect-uri** for the iOS and android application? The **OIDC Provider** need to redirect user back to the application with the **authorization-code**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most mainstream option is to use the AppAuth pattern from [RFC8252](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8252.html#section-7.1) and a private URI scheme value registered with the mobile operating system, such as this. The URL is also registered against the client in the OIDC provider:

```
com.mycompany.myapp:/callback
```

My blog posts will get you up and running with a basic sample:

- [Android](https://authguidance.com/android-setup/)
- [iOS](https://authguidance.com/ios-setup/)

Comment: Thanks @Gary Archer, these blog posts are helpfull for me.

Comment: How can we use this kind of redirect_uri "com.mycompany.myapp:/callback" ? I'm having this issue : `Invalid redirect: Must use either http or https as the scheme.` It's to handle SSO sign on, with a google provider, i need to specify a redirect URI...

Comment: What authorization server are you using? Any respected one should support a private URI scheme based URL?